# Difference between Tags and Taxonomy in a CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, tags, orchardcms, taxonomy

Is it: Tags vs Taxonomy?

They both conceptually seem to be the same thing: Categorizing content. Although, taxonomy allows hierarchy whereas tags don't. In Orchard 1.4, should we be using taxonomy instead of tags? Are there instances where we could/should both? I guess this question could apply to any CMS system.

Note: I am building Modules in Orchard so this determine my approach to doing so.

Comment: oh wow, didn't I answer this exact same question on CodePlex a couple of hours ago? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today the Taxonomy module doesn't handle free editing of 'categories'. Also Tags provides auto-completion. In the future, Tags will be deprecated, and Taxonomy will be used, but only when Taxonomy is able to handle free vocabularies and auto-completion.

Comment: So it seems that tags allow more freedom in categorizing than taxonomy.